# Relative pronoun "whose" as an object rather than a subject

Tags: relative-pronouns

Is it grammatical to say

> I have a friend whose father I respect so much

when there are the following facts:

1. I have a friend
2. I respect his/her father so much

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativizer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the use of "whose", your sentence is grammatical.  "Whose" is an adjective and is not either subjective or objective.  It is the noun ("father") that is the object, not "whose".  "Whose" is simply giving more information about "father".  Your use of "so much", while common, is not ideal.  It would be better to use "very much".  As it stands, you respect him so much as what?  You might say something like "There are few people I respect so much as Johnny's father."  There you are comparing other people with Johnny's father.  It would also be fairly common to use "as much as" or "more than" in that case.

Comment: The comparison form is **as much as** ...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "so much" without an explicit comparison. It is usually more emphatic than "very much" - an exclamation.

Comment: @ColinFine: I didn't say that it is *wrong*.  I said that it isn't ideal ... and it isn't.